# Showing a window at launch prevents access to main table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstableview

I am developing a chat application for Mac. Once I log in into my application, I get a notification window showing the users who are online. I am controlling the fade in and fade out effect of this window using an `NSTimer`. My problem is that until all my notifications disappear, I am unable to access the main table view. I am stuck on this issue. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please clarify: _I am unable to access the main table view._

Comment: Unable to access in the sense i cant be able to perform any task by clicking the coressponding outline view.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the notification window in a background thread?
By calling performSelectorInBackground